# Creating a Concatenated Code from another field value with unique number In Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am generating a supplier form, where I will add the `Supplier_Name` and the `Supplier_Code` is auto-generated by taking the first two characters of `Supplier_Name` and adding a unique number for when 2 suppliers have the same first 2 characters e.g.:

- SundriesSupplier 1 = SU01;
- SugarSupplier 1 = SU02

I am new to VBA and tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
Private Sub Supplier_Name_AfterUpdate()
    Dim DB As Database
    Dim RS As Recordset
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim var1 As String

    var1 = Left(Me.Supplier_Name.Value, 2)

    SQL = "SELECT Supplier_ID, LEFT(Supplier_Name,2) AS charsupplier, count (Supplier_Name) AS countSupplier " _
        & "FROM Suppliers " _
        & "WHERE charsupplier = var1 " _
        & "ORDER BY Supplier_ID"

     Set DB = CurrentDb
     Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset)

    Me.Supplier_Code = var1 & Format$(RS!countSupplier, "00")

    End Sub
```

If anyone can help or suggest an alternative method that would be great thanks.

> EDIT: I think the flaw in my approach may be that if this is on the new record, the supplier_ID is not saved to the table and will not be available for query?

Comment: What you are trying to do is possible but seems unnecessary and taxing on the surface. Why not use AutoNumber to have Access generate a unique id for you?

Comment: For the old database that is in place, the supplier code is entered manually and is used away from the database. To avoid confusion, or the user entering a wrong supplier code, I would like the new database to generate this code so the user doesn't have to.

Comment: What is the name of the field you are storing the Supplier_Code? Are you appending these entries to the Suppliers table? If not, then what other table are you using to store the records that contain this new Supplier_Code?

Comment: yes I would like to save supplier_Code to suppliers table. very amateur of me, but, I have realised that I will need to save the record first. correct? I was distracted by the supplier_ID showing up on the form. However, I don't think it is in the table at this point because I am able to cancel the form and the supplier_ID isn't saved.

Comment: There must be a different approach but I don't know how to go about it

Comment: While someone can/will help you create a 'GetNextSupCod(strName as String) as String' function, I can see some issues with the way you have the code in the AfterUpdate of the Supplier textbox. (can potentially create erroneous suppliers if the user edits the name after initial input; also, user might be entering the same supplier more than once, by mistake...so you might want to notify them before they commit.) I would suggest an [Add New Supplier] Button instead of AfterUpdate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to work out my issue with the following code:

```
 Private Sub Supplier_Name_LostFocus()

If IsNull([Supplier_Code]) Then
   Dim DB As Database
   Dim RS As Recordset
   Dim var2 As String
   Dim var1 As String
   Dim var3 As String


   var1 = Left(Me.Supplier_Name, 2)

   var2 = "SELECT count(*) AS CountSupplier " & _
          "FROM Suppliers " & _
          "WHERE left(Suppliers.[Supplier_Name],2)='" & var1 & "';"
'   MsgBox (var2)



   Set DB = CurrentDb
   Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset(var2, dbOpenDynaset)
   var3 = RS!CountSupplier + 1
   Me.Supplier_Code = UCase(var1) & Format(var3, "00")
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started based on a button called cmdAddNewSupplier. You should have enough to adapt the example to your needs. *(Sorry, I edited because I forgot to mention that the example code is using a fictitious table called [SUPPLIERS] with a fictitious column name of [SUPPLIER_NAME]; you'll need to replace with the name of your table and column.)*

```
Private Sub cmdAddNewSupplier_Click()
  'TODO: create some error handling
  'TODO: check for null value of SupplierName Textbox; notify user and exit if its null
  'TODO: check for less than 2 chars for supplier name; notify user and exit if it's less than 2 chars (seems impossible, but can happen)
  Dim strSupCode As String 'the eventual unique id of the new supplier

  'make sure the user wants to add the supplier if the name already exists
  'all we are doing is utilizing DLookup so we don't have to deal with recordset object
  If Not IsNull(DLookup("[SUPPLIER_NAME]", "[SUPPLIERS]", "[SUPPLIER_NAME] = " & Chr(34) & Me.Supplier_Name & Chr(34))) Then
    If MsgBox(Me.Supplier_Name & " Already Exists!" & vbCrLf & "Are you sure that you want to add them?", vbYesNoCancel Or vbQuestion, "Please Confirm") <> vbYes Then
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End If

  strSupCode = GetSupplierCode(Me.Supplier_Name)

  MsgBox Me.Supplier_Name & vbCrLf & strSupCode 'test it out to make sure it's working before doing anything for real
End Sub

Function GetSupplierCode(strSupplierName As String) As String
  Dim nLoop As Long
  Dim strCode As String

  strCode = UCase(Left(strSupplierName, 2))

  'The supplier name is unique or the user means to add another supplier with the same name
  For nLoop = 1 To 100 '100 same names is unlikely, eh?

    'create a temp supplier code starting with 1 and increment
    'the return value is being set, so all we have to do is jump out of function when unique is found
    GetSupplierCode = strCode & Format(nLoop, "00")

    'TODO: utilize DLookup to check for existence; will leave this part to you;
    'dont forget you are looking at CODE and not NAME here as we did in the button click function

    '      if isnull(DLookup(<enter the required parameters>)) then
    '         exit function 'jump out of the function because this one should be the next unique
    '      end if

  Next

End Function
```